# How to find if record is created or updated in updateOrCreate function?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've a simple post form. Records are saved to database with `updateOrCreate` function.

I've following records to be stored,

1. user_id
2. product_id
3. review
4. rating

After submitting form, `user_id` and `product_id` are used to check if record exist or not. If exist, record will be updated otherwise new record created with the function.

```
public function updateOrCreate($input)
{
    return $this->model->updateOrCreate(['product_id'=> $input['product_id'],'user_id'=>$input['user_id']],['rating'=>$input['rating'],'review'=>$input['review']]);
}
```

Is there any built in method to find new record created or existing record updated ?

Any kind of suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Check with an extra `find()` call?

Comment: @vivek_23 I don't have id of the record

Comment: Like `if(empty(Product::find($input['product_id']))`

Comment: you can use Model Observer to check whether the record updated or created

Comment: or use @Namoshek answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a public property on Eloquent models called `$wasRecentlyCreated`. It is set [when an insert is performed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/adb72b434903336ff75cc8d21a3026e5835a3be4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L769-L812). And it will only be `true` after an insert for the same request; not for consecutive requests. If an update has been performed, it will be `false`.

Be aware that the property is also only `true` for the exact same model instance. If you reload the model with `Product::find($id)`, it will be `false`. What happens if you call `refresh()` on a model, is unfortunately unclear to me.

Comment: How about checking for `find()` before DB operation?

Comment: It performs another database operation and therefore costs valuable time and resources. It is basically useless, if you have the information already on your hand with the property described in the answer.

Comment: I've multiple users and multiple products, it will work when different user rate different products consecutively

Comment: Each rating is an individual request to the server - so, yes, why not?

Comment: @Namoshek Select on a DB table on primary key is pretty fast. So it wouldn't effect runtime performance and there will be no difference in user experience. If `find()` returns me a model, we could update it there itself with `save()`. I am pretty sure Laravel does it the same way when it checks for `$this->exists`., because PDO insert or update gives no. of affected rows which should be the same.

Comment: @vivek_23 Well, in the end it comes down to how clean you want your code to be. Of course you can check yourself if a record exists and perform the update/insert conditionally, but you just add more lines of code for effectively the same outcome. If you do `find()` and then `create()`/`update()`, performance should be the same as `createOrUpdate()`. But going for `find()` and `createOrUpdate()` would be indeed unnecessary due to the additional query.

Comment: @Namoshek Of course my argument was irrelevant to the OP's post. Sorry for that. Also, I meant `save()` after `find()`, so 2 queries. I think Laravel also does it the same way under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine if the model or given attribute(s) have been modified. And [wasChanged()](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_wasChanged) method will help to identify if the model is updated or not.

```
$model = $this->model->updateOrCreate(['product_id'=> $input['product_id'],'user_id'=>$input['user_id']],['rating'=>$input['rating'],'review'=>$input['review']]);

// It will return true if the record have been modified
$wasChanged = $model->wasChanged();
if ( $wasChanged ) {
    // updated
}
else {
   // created
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: If the product is already in DB and there are no changes in rating and review, in that case, it will not work properly. Because then it will enter into the created block.